# SQL - nested select queries

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image: DATA SETS]

I want to select all `dealercode` (distinct) and `introducercode` with iapn. Bbut iapn must be a highest value only.

e.g.

```
dealercode = 7 and iapin = 3 and introducercode = 3
```

like that (THIS MUST BE A ONLY VALUE FOR DEALERCODE)

This is my query:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT 
      dealercode, iapin as iapin,
      (SELECT introducercode) as introducecode
  FROM 
      dealerplacement d
  where 
      exists (SELECT MIN(iapin) FROM dealerplacement )
  ORDER BY 
      dealercode, iapin ASC
```

I have attached with this post data set to this code.

[image]

This is the structure. I want to get result as below.
       DEALERCODE 1200 iapn 003 and introducercode 203.   only.

current database as below.

```
  1200  001  201
  1200  002  202
  1200  003  203
```

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why not just use `MAX` and `GROUP BY` or is there something else I am missing

```
SELECT  dealercode,
        introducercode,
        MAX(iapin) iapin
FROM    dealerplacement d
GROUP BY    dealercode,
            introducercode
```

[Aggregate Functions (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173454.aspx)

**EDIT**

Re the changes to your request, you might want to try something like

```
SELECT  d.*
FROM    dealerplacement d INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT  dealercode, 
                    MAX(iapin) iapin 
            FROM    dealerplacement d 
            GROUP BY    dealercode
        ) dM    ON  d.dealercode = dM.dealercode
                AND d.iapin = dM.iapin
```

Comment: Can you may post your data in your question, and also, what are your expectations regarding the introducercode?

Comment: I added post as answer.please check it.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you want the MINIMUM iapin based on your example result. To get the proper corresponding `introducecode`, you'll need to use a subselect:

```
SELECT a.dealercode, a.iapin, a.introducecode
FROM dealerplacement a
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT dealercode, MIN(iapin) AS miniapin
    FROM dealerplacement
    GROUP BY dealercode
) b ON a.dealercode = b.dealercode AND a.iapin = b.miniapin
```